# PyQt5 get input with multiple values

Tags: pyqt5

I would like to in a for cycle open a new dialog (popup) window with fields
that I will save to a database
e.g.

```
onPrintButton(self):
  for file in files:
     ...
     openDialogWindow() the for cycle will stop here until I press OK button with filled in values
```

In the opened dialog window there will be various fields (some of them already prefilled)
e.g.

```
date
file_name
printer_name
```

etc.

When I click the OK button the values will be saved to a DB (you can just print them to the console)
and the for cycle will continue where it stopped.

Could you please show me scaffolding of such functionality (which Qt classes to use etc.)?

Comment: Create your own [QDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html), add the input widgets you need and a [QDialogButtonBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html), then call `exec()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, your QDialog can have anything you want.

```
class Dialog(QDialog):

    accepted = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.date = QDateEdit()
        self.date.setDisplayFormat('MMM d, yyyy')
        self.date.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        self.file_name = QLineEdit()
        self.file_name.textEdited[str].connect(self.unlock)
        self.printer_name = QLineEdit()
        self.btn = QPushButton('OK')
        self.btn.setDisabled(True)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.ok_pressed)

        form = QFormLayout(self)
        form.addRow('Date', self.date)
        form.addRow('*File Name', self.file_name)
        form.addRow('Printer Name', self.printer_name)
        form.addRow(self.btn)

    def unlock(self, text):
        if text:
            self.btn.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.btn.setDisabled(True)

    def ok_pressed(self):
        values = {'Date': self.date.date(),
                  'File': self.file_name.text(),
                  'Printer': self.printer_name.text()}
        self.accepted.emit(values)
        self.accept()
```

And when you call it from the parent widget:

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        dg = Dialog()
        dg.accepted.connect(self.do_something)
        dg.exec_()

    def do_something(self, values):
        print(values['File'], values['Date'], values['Printer'])
```

Comment: Thank you. And how can I refer to dg.file_name in self.do_something?

Comment: The values are passed as a dictionary, I edited the bottom.

Comment: And can I somehow enforce that a field is mandatory (must be filled in)? I rather ask here, because it would be short question.

Comment: @xralf Sure, you could disable the Ok button until all the required fields are filled in.

Comment: Could you please show it, if it's not complex? I have found only [this](https://impatientprogrammer.net/2018/07/06/pyside-pyqt-qwizard-in-3-minutes/) where is talked about asterisk.

Comment: @xralf That feature is unique to QWizardPage, I believe. I edited the answer showing what I mean. In this case, file_name is a required field, so connect its `textEdited` signal to enable the OK button when the user has entered text.